Language Switcher Not Working
Followed the guide here: https://civicrm.org/blog/ayduns/language-switcher
Have English and Spanish (Mexico) installed.
When I switch the language by using a URL on an event link civicrm/event/register?reset=1&id=168&lcMessages=es_ES I still see the English UI elements untranslated, such as "Register".
I installed this extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/language-switcher and have switched back and forth from English to Spanish (Mexico) and it does not show any CiviCRM backend element in Spanish.
What am I missing?

I wrote that blog post a long time ago but haven't look at it much since then!  It seems to be mostly working:

Credit card & billing info labels are translated, although the "Your Registration Info" is not.
You need the language translations installed (see uplang) and the languages enabled in the 'Additional Languages' box.  'Inherit CMS Language' should be 'No'.
In some quick testing, I got some odd combinations of translated/untranslated content when switching between various settings which I guess may be related to caching.

Thank you. I have https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.l10n.update installed, which downloaded the files for es_MX, instead of Uplang. Could that be why it's not working? On my install, nothing is translated, but I see the civicrm.mo files in /l10n/es_MX
